# Compare two arrays of primitives in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, compare, primitive-types

I know about Arrays.deepEquals(Object[], Object[]) but this doesn't work for primitive types (due limitations of arrays and autoboxing, see [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517751/java-generic-method-but-array-of-primitive-data-types-does-not-autobox)).

With that in mind, is this the most efficient approach?

```
boolean byteArrayEquals(byte[] a, byte[] b) {
    if (a == null && b == null)
        return true;

    if (a == null || b == null)
        return false;

    if (a.length != b.length)
        return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] != b[i])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Change your first comparison to be:

```
if (a == b)
    return true;
```

This not only catches the "both null" cases, but also "compare an array to itself" case.

However, for a simpler alternative - use [`Arrays.equals`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals(byte[],%20byte[])) which has overloads for each primitive type. (The implementation is very similar to yours, except it hoists the array length out of the loop. On .NET that can be an anti-optimization, but I guess the JRE library implementors probably know better for the JVM :)

Comment: I thought there was a library method, but tweakt threw me off by mentioning deepEquals() right off the bat. Arrays.equals() does exactly what this method with your change does, although it also stores a.length in a temporary variable (before comparing lengths).

Comment: You may find the VM ignore the implementation in the library and inline its own.

Answer (score 15):

I think the most efficient should be to use the helper methods in the [Arrays](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) class, because they might be implemented more cleverly. So in this case, use

```
Arrays.equals(a, b);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help anyone, but this seems to be working:

```
        if(type == type_BooleanArray) {
            boolean eq = Arrays.equals((boolean[]) thisObj, (boolean[]) thatObj);
            if(!eq) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if(type == type_ByteArray) {
            boolean eq = Arrays.equals((byte[]) thisObj, (byte[]) thatObj);
            if(!eq) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if(type == type_ShortArray) {
            boolean eq = Arrays.equals((short[]) thisObj, (short[]) thatObj);
            if(!eq) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if(type == type_CharArray) {
            boolean eq = Arrays.equals((char[]) thisObj, (char[]) thatObj);
            if(!eq) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if(type == type_IntArray) {
            boolean eq = Arrays.equals((int[]) thisObj, (int[]) thatObj);
            if(!eq) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if(type == type_LongArray) {
            boolean eq = Arrays.equals((long[]) thisObj, (long[]) thatObj);
            if(!eq) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if(type == type_FloatArray) {
            boolean eq = Arrays.equals((float[]) thisObj, (float[]) thatObj);
            if(!eq) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if(type == type_DoubleArray) {
            boolean eq = Arrays.equals((double[]) thisObj, (double[]) thatObj);
            if(!eq) {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            if(!thisObj.equals(thatObj)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Apparently `array.equals(otherArray)` does a `array == otherArray`, and not what you would expect.