# Hashing password using salt

Tags: java, hash, passwords, password-protection

I am producing a hashed value of a password with salt.My code:

```
  `String psw="hello";  
   String tobehashed="";
   tobehashed=salt+psw;
   MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
   byte[] digest = md.digest(tobehashed.getBytes());
   System.out.println("Digest:"+digest);`
```

I have produced salt by providing seed as current time in milliseconds,I have no issues with salt(I m getting random values) but irrespective of salt I am getting same hash value..

Actually the purpose of salt is to get different hash values..
This is my output;
       `Random nubr:-2098016229(this keeps changing)
        Digest:[B@ca0b6(this remains same)`
Waht is the solution??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are printing out the result of `digest.toString()`, which in the case of a byte array does *not* convert the bytes to meaningful output. It just prints `[B` (which is the code for byte array), `@`, and then a hex address. You will see this output often as you get more experience with Java.

You will need to use a loop to iterate through the bytes in the digest and print them individually.

Comment: But If I need to compare hash values later,I have to compare both hash values by iterating a loop.Is it right???

Comment: @user1258724: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630808/compare-two-arrays-of-primitives-in-java for answers to that.

Answer (score 4):

B@ca0b6 is not the content of the byte array, it is the toString() representation. Iterate of the bytes of the array and print them individually.

Comment: But If I need to compare hash values later,I have to compare both hash values by iterating a loop.Is it correct???