# Java Collections.rotate() with an array doesn't work

Tags: java, arrays, list, collections

I have the following Java code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] test = {1,2,3,4,5};
        Collections.rotate(Arrays.asList(test), -1);
        for(int i = 0; i < test.length; i++) { System.out.println(test[i]); }
    }

}
```

I want the array to be rotated, but the output I get is

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Why is this?

And is there an alternative solution?

EDIT:

So this works:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] test = {1,2,3,4,5};
        List<Integer> testList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i = 0; i < test.length; i++) { testList.add(test[i]); }
        Collections.rotate(testList, -1);
        for(int i = 0; i < test.length; i++) { System.out.println(testList.get(i)); }
    }

}
```

But Arrays.asList is supposed to return a list that when written to, copies the changes to the array. Is there any way to fix this without manually doing the conversion from array to list?

I (think that I) can't afford to waste that much CPU time and memory to do the conversion.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is a tricky problem: yes, `asList` backs the `List` it returns with the array, and changes to the `List` will "write-through" to the array. However, due to how varargs of `T...` interacts with an array of primitive type in this case, you're actually creating a list with 1 element!

```
    int[] test = {1,2,3,4,5};
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(test).size());
    // prints "1"
```

Let's try something different:

```
    int[] test = {1,2,3,4,5};
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(test);
    // "Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<int[]> to List<Integer>"
```

As you see, the varargs with an `int[]` doesn't work the way you intended, and the compiler gives an error. `Arrays.asList` actually returns a 1-element `List<int[]>` instead of a 5-element `List<Integer>`.

Using `Integer[]` instead of `int[]` works as expected:

```
    Integer[] test = {1,2,3,4,5};
    Collections.rotate(Arrays.asList(test), -1);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test));
    // prints "[2, 3, 4, 5, 1]"
```

---

#### More explanation

The full signature of `asList` is [`<T> List<T> Arrays.asList(T... a)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29). Note that `T` can't be `int` in this case, for the same reason why you can't have a `List<int>` in Java: `T` needs to be a reference type.

Consider the following snippet:

```
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
    // prints "[1, 2, 3]"
```

What happens here is that each `int` is boxed into an `Integer`, and the varargs mechanism "works" and `asList` creates a list of 3 elements. Now consider the following form instead:

```
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(new int[] { 1,2,3 }));
    // prints "[[I@xxxxxx]"
```

Now the argument to `asList` is an `int[]`. `T` can't be an `int`, therefore, the `T...` varargs mechanism "fails", and `asList` only gets one element, and it's an `int[]`, instead of the `int` values themselves.

Now consider this form:

```
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(new Integer[] { 1,2,3 }));
    // prints "[1, 2, 3]"
```

Now since `Integer[]` is a `T...`, `asList` gets 3 elements as expected.

#### See also

- [Java: Array of primitive data types does not autobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517751/java-array-of-primitive-data-types-does-not-autobox)

  - An `int[]` does not autobox to an `Integer[]`

Comment: See also TS-1188 2006 JavaOne Conference, Java Puzzlers presentation Puzzle 7. "Fib O'Nacci"

Comment: asList() is allowing 'test' because it is also a reference type, as arrays are Objects. So when you say, Arrays.asList(test) the 'array of integers' is kept in List and is returned.