# Compare content of a ring buffer

Tags: c#

I need to check the reception of a specific sequence of numbers for example 3,3,3,2,2,3 but this repeating sequence can start at a different position for example 3,3,3,3,2,2

I have created a ring buffer that store the received number and compare to all possible sequences

```
class MFMSequence {
    int _index = 0;
    int[] _buffer = new int[6];
    public void add(int value) {
        _buffer[_index] = value;
        _index = (_index + 1) % 6;
    }
    public bool is4e() {
        return (_buffer.SequenceEqual(new int[] { 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3 }) ||
                _buffer.SequenceEqual(new int[] { 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2 }) ||
                _buffer.SequenceEqual(new int[] { 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2 }) ||
                _buffer.SequenceEqual(new int[] { 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3 }) ||
                _buffer.SequenceEqual(new int[] { 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3 }) ||
                _buffer.SequenceEqual(new int[] { 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3 }));
    }
    public bool is00() {
        return (_buffer.SequenceEqual(new int[] { 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 }));
    }
}
```

This is working but I find it ugly! Any idea on how to code this more elegantly

Comment: It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site, but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their requirements](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are a bit more strict than this site.

Comment: Sounds to me similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7693992/1997232) (unfortunately unanswered) question.

Comment: This question looks like it might be a pretty good fit for [Code Review.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), provided that (a) you want _every aspect_ of your code reviewed, not just some, (b) your code is _already working_, and (c) you're asking for a review of _concrete, real code_, not abstract design (whether or not it's expressed as code). If you agree with all of those, please read about [what's on topic](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and, if your question fits that, delete it here and repost it on CR.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
private bool CheckIt(int[] checkFor, int[] have)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, checkFor.Length).Any(i =>
        checkFor.Concat(checkFor).Skip(i).Take(have.Length).SequenceEqual(have)
    );
}
```

Not entirely 'pretty', but it's a quick mockup and I'm sure there are lots of improvements to have. Also works for any number of items. Usage:

```
var checkFor = new int[] { 3,3,3,2,2,3 };
var have = new int[] { 3,2,2,3,3,3 };
var result = CheckIt(checkFor, have);
```

Comment: First one returns fals for `var checkFor = new int[] { 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3 };` and it is wrong.

Comment: @Alexander Ah yes, you're absolutely right. Will remove that solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could write a loop to compare all possible sequences, then at least it would extend to any number of items without having to change the code:

```
public static bool RingBufferContains(int[] buffer, int[] target)
{
    if (buffer == null || target == null || buffer.Length != target.Length)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("buffer and target must be non-null and the same length.");

    int n = buffer.Length;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {
            if (buffer[(i+j)%n] != target[j])
                break;

            if (j == n - 1)
                return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

This is an O(N^2) solution, like yours.

Test code:

```
int[] buffer = { 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3 };
int[] target = { 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3 };
Console.WriteLine(RingBufferContains(buffer, target));
```

Comment: This is an O(N^2) solution (original solution is O(N^2) too)

Comment: @Alexander Oops, that was a typo - meant to say N^2

Answer (score 0):

I think Rob and Matthew Watson solutions much more better than hardcode all possibilities. Matthew's code is more optimal, but Rob's looks more pretty. If your sequences are small both of them are good enough. But if you have much more bigger sequences or if you want to develop some general solution you should optimize it.
My idea is to set start position of sequence to min or max element and compare sequences only one time.
If we have several min or max elements we have several possible start position and we need to compare several times. In the worst case it will be N/2 times (sequence { min, min, min, max, max, max }).