# Java, will (low + high) >>> 1 overflow?

Tags: java, overflow

I am looking at Java 1.8 Api.
In the `java.util.Arrays.binarySearch(int[] a, int key)`, I have found this piece of code.

```
int low = fromIndex;
int high = toIndex - 1;

while (low <= high) {
    int mid = (low + high) >>> 1;
    int midVal = a[mid];

    if (midVal < key)
        low = mid + 1;
    else if (midVal > key)
        high = mid - 1;
    else
        return mid; // key found
}
return -(low + 1);  // key not found.
```

In this piece of code `(low + high) >>> 1` will not overflow.
Can anybody tell me why it happened? I test it with my own code.

```
int low = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int high = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
System.out.println((low + high) / 2);
System.out.println((low + high) >>> 1);
```

So, does it mean that the logical right shift will take the overflow bit into consideration?

Comment: The `>>>` treats the values as 32-bit unsigned int, and the sum of two 31-bit signed ints cannot be larger than a 32-bit unsigned int so there is no overflow for the purpose of this operation. Note: if you used `>>` you could have a problem.

Answer (score 6):

You are correct that the expression will overflow for sufficiently large values of `low` and `high`. You may get an incorrect result if one of the values is negative.

However, you cannot get a negative number in a binary search method, because both `low` and `high` are indexes into the array; they must be positive. Therefore, the result of the addition will overflow only into the sign bit; it will not create a carry bit.

Since Java's `>>>` operator will shift the sign bit without sign extension, you would get the correct result even for two `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Essentially, the `>>>` operator lets you treat the 32-nd bit as an extra bit of unsigned storage, even though the bit belongs to a signed type.

Answer (score 2):

If the result of `low + high` overflows and becomes negative, neither `(low + high) / 2` nor `(low + high) >> 1` would work.

`a >> 1` keeps the sign bit of the original, so a negative value for `a` gives a negative result

`a >>> 1` works by introducing a zero sign bit, so the result cannot be negative for any `a`.

Demonstration:

```
int low = 1;
int high = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
System.out.println(low + high);         // This is negative
System.out.println((low + high) >>> 1); // This is positive, and the desired result.
System.out.println((low + high) >> 1);  // This is negative
System.out.println((low + high) / 2);   // This is negative
```

Because of overflow, finding the mid-value of two `int` values is very easy to get wrong. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844165/safe-integer-middle-value-formula) for expressions that work for positive and negative values.