# Java, will (low + high) >> 1 overflow?

Tags: java, overflow, average, bitwise-operators

I know that `>>` is for signed and `>>>` is for unsigned

Similar questions that do not answer my question:

[Java, will (low + high) >>> 1 overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33616299/java-will-low-high-1-overflow)

[Safe integer middle value formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844165/safe-integer-middle-value-formula)

According to the second link, why do they conclude that: 
`avg = (low & high) + ((low ^ high) >> 1);` will avoid overflow?

Why can't they just use this instead : `(low + high) >> 1`?

(This is for binary search in java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `(low + high) >> 1` may overflow if the sum is high enough.  As you know, `>>>` is for unsigned, so that it will always shift in a `0` on the most significant side.  This turns out to be very important in case it does overflow.

The trick to using `(low + high)` even with overflow is that information is still retained.  If it does overflow, the maximum possible mathematical sum is still `Integer.MAX_VALUE * 2`, which would still be representable as an unsigned `int`, if Java had one.  But we can *treat* the sum as an unsigned int when dividing by 2 by using the unsigned right shift operator, `>>>`.  When bit-shifting to the right by `1`, this lets us treat the sum as an unsigned `int`, "un-overflowing" the `int`.

Using `>>` here won't work if the sum overflows, because it will overflow into a negative number and `>>` will shift in a `1`, keeping the value negative.  This results in an incorrect average calculation (2 positive numbers whose sum overflows will result in a negative average).

Whether you're using `>>>` or `>>`, overflow is a possibility.  So both can overflow.  But only `>>>` will handle the case well, properly "un-overflowing" the sum.

The trick

```
avg = (low & high) + ((low ^ high) >> 1);
```

is another way calculating the average when the sum may overflow.  This avoids the overflow entirely.  This is breaking down the sum into 2 parts -- the "carry" bits and the "non-carry" bits.

When working with addition, the bits that are carried over to the next more significant bit are when both bits are set -- `low & high`.  Normally in addition, these bits have to be shifted left, but we're calculating the average of 2 numbers, so we would shift right in the end also.  The net result: no shift here.

The bits that aren't carried are either a `1` if the bits are different or a `0` if the bits are the same -- that's where `(low ^ high)` comes from (XOR).  Normally in addition, these bits aren't shifted, but we're calculating the average of 2 numbers, so we would shift right in the end also.  This shift shows up as `>> 1`.  The `&` and `^` operators don't overflow, so `>>` will work just fine here.

Example: Average of 1100 (12) and 1010 (10)

```
1100 & 1010 = 1000
1100 ^ 1010 = 0110, 0110 >> 1 = 0011
1000 + 0011 = 1011 (11)
```