# Java: Generic Class Exception

Tags: java, generics, exception, singly-linked-list

I was designing a generic linked list to create a linked list of Strings.
However I keep getting this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Node.<init>(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
at LinkedList.addNode(LinkedList.java:10)
at LinkedList.<init>(LinkedList.java:22)
at Trial.main(Trial.java:7)
```

From the stack trace , the error is generated at LinkedList's addNode() method. Im including the definition to this method as well as the definition of the Node class. 
**LinkedList addNode()**

```
public void addNode(T n) {
        Node<T> temp = new Node<T>(n);
        if(start==null) {
            start = temp;
            current = start;
        } else {
            end.setNext(temp);
        }
        end =temp;
    }
```

**Node.java**

```
public class Node<T>{
private T n;
Node next;
Node(T n) {
    this.n = n;
    next = null;
}
public void setNext(Node nextNode) {
    next = nextNode;
}
public Node getNext() {
    return next;
}
public T getN() {
    return n;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    if(n instanceof String)
        return n.toString();
    else {
        return T.toString();
    }
}
```

}

**LinkedList.java**

```
public class LinkedList<T>{
Node start;
Node end;
Node current;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 901L;
    LinkedList(T n) {
        addNode(n);
    }
    public void addNode(T n) {
        Node<T> temp = new Node<>(n);
        if(start==null) {
            start = temp;
            current = start;
        } else {
            end.setNext(temp);
        }
        end =temp;
    }

    LinkedList(T[] n) {
        for(T print : n)
        addNode(print);
    }
    public void addNode(T[] n) {
        if(n!=null) {
            for (T values : n) {
                addNode(values);
            }
        }
    }

    public void incC() {
        current = current.getNext();
    }
    public void insert(T n) {
        Node newNode = new Node(n);
            if(current==start){
                newNode.setNext(current);
                start = newNode;
            }else {
                Node tempstart = start;
                Node prevAdd=null;
                while(tempstart!=current){
                    prevAdd = tempstart;
                    tempstart = tempstart.getNext();
                }
                prevAdd.setNext(newNode);
                newNode.setNext(current);
            }
    }

    public void find(T x) {
        Node tempstart;
        tempstart = start;
        while (tempstart!=null) {
            if(tempstart.getN()==x) {
                System.out.println("Element found");
                tempstart = tempstart.getNext();
            } else {
                tempstart = tempstart.getNext();
            }
        }
    }
    public void delete(T x) {
        Node previous=null;
        Node tempstart = start;
        while(tempstart!=null) {
        if(tempstart.getN()==x) {
            if(previous ==null) {
                previous = tempstart;
                tempstart = tempstart.getNext();
                start = tempstart;
                previous.setNext(null);
                previous = null;
            } else {
                tempstart = tempstart.getNext();
                previous.setNext(tempstart);
            }
        }else {
            previous = tempstart;
            tempstart = tempstart.getNext();
        }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        Node tempNode = start;
        String str = "Values: ";
        while (tempNode!=null) {
            str = str + " " + tempNode.toString();
            tempNode = tempNode.getNext();
        }
        return str;
    }
}
```

**Trial.java**

```
public class Trial {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] para = {"Hollo","this","is","me"};
    LinkedList<String> L1;
    L1 = new LinkedList<String>(para);
    System.out.println(L1);
}
```

Comment: can you share your code in Trial.main(...) which is calling the LinkedList

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare the `start`, `end`, and `current` fields in `LinkedList< T >` and the `next` field in `Node< T >` as type `Node< T >`, not `Node`.  Don't use raw types anywhere in the code, because they translate into `Node< Object >`.

Comment: That solved it for me , Sir however , I have a question.
Why isnt next in Node class dectared with <T> and only in LinkedList<>

Comment: @FasihKhatib, I'm sorry but I don't follow your question.  Did you eliminate *all* the raw mentions of `Node` yet?

Comment: Yes, I replaced every instance of Node with Node<T> :)
Uhm... do you have any simple exercises on this topic of Generic class ? I would like to practice a bit more 0:)

Comment: Primitives will be "auto-boxed".  If you call some generic method `f( T t )` with a primitive like `42`, Java will infer the type `Integer` (not `int`) for the argument.

Comment: Ah, alright. So in my above program , when I tried to pass an int[] I got an error that no suitable method is found.
int[] numbers = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};
LinkedList<Integer> L1 = new LinkedList<>(numbers);
This was flagged as error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517751/java-array-of-primitive-data-types-does-not-autobox

Answer (score 4):

```
return T.toString();
```

this doesn't work. T is a type variable and only available at compile time due to type erasure.

But apart from that, I can't see what's wrong, you need to poost more code from your LinkedList class.

Comment: **@Sean** Well, If I was to create a linked list of Integers then I would require that won't I ? I changed the code a little after I posted this. It looks like this now
ublic String toString() {

  if(n instanceof String)

   return n.toString();

  else {

   return T.toString(n);

  }

 }

Comment: @FasihKhatib no, just write `return n.toString()` or null-safe: `return String.valueOf(n)`

Comment: Alright , I will edit the post to include the entire defn of LinkedList.java

Comment: `T.toString()` _won't work._  You should almost certainly just return `n.toString()` in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

Your class `Node`does not compile, so it is likely that you should first fix that issue before continuing:

```
return T.toString();
```

does not make sense. Probably that just writing this:

```
return n.toString();
```

is enough for now.

Comment: @FasihKhatib Then edit your question and post the complete code for LinkedList.

Comment: @FasihKhatib I just ran your code without problems. I only replaced your Node.toString() with `public String toString() {   return n.toString();}
` and I could run it without problems. Are you sure that you have properly recompiled your classes?

Comment: Yes , Sir. Im using JCrestor LE so all the classes associated with Trial.java (which has the main() method that creates linked list) so I dont have to manually do anyhting

Comment: I believe **Node<T> temp = new Node<>(n);** is the error. Could it be ?

Comment: @FasihKhatib The error you are getting is that the constructor Node with an `Object` argument does not exist (but the class `Node` is actually found on the JVM's classpath). Since your code actually contains that constructor, I would have suspected that your class had not been recompiled when you wrote the toString method. Maybe try a "Clean" on your project

Comment: How do I do that ? and how can I get around the Node constructor issue ?

Comment: @FasihKhatib I have never used JCreator (personnally I use Eclipse) so I can't help you on that. Possibly, one option is to delete manually the `.class` files to force the compilation step. Your Node constructor has no issues. As I told you earlier, I could run your code without the error your reported. So to me, there must something else. It could be your IDE, but it's hard to say.

Comment: so , Hello This Is Me was printed properly for you ?

Answer (score 1):

In Node.java, in the method

```
@Override 
public String toString() { 
    if(n instanceof String) 
        return n.toString(); 
    else { 
        return T.toString(); 
    } 
}
```

// the below statement thows compilation error. 
 return T.toString();

Comment: **@JackAss** I even Tried
return n.toString();
but it still gives that error. Probably something to do with Node.java's constructor

Comment: toString() is non static method generally. So if T is a class then T.toString() means that class must have a default toString() as static. but that is not true. hence compilation error. If you take any Class by default it extends Object class hence you get non-static toString(). Hence n.toString() works and T.toString() results in compilation failure

Comment: I removed that statement so only n.toString() is there now but still there is an error. 
could it be there is an error in how I defined Node.java class ?

Comment: public void addNode(T n) { 
        Node<T> temp = new Node<>(n); 
        if(start==null) { 
            start = temp; 
            current = start; 
        } else { 
            end.setNext(temp); 
        } 
        end =temp; 
    } 
here  Node<T> temp = new Node<>(n);  is not a valid statement.

Comment: **@JackAss** So how do I modify that ? Node is a stand alone class that encapsulates the data element of the List and has a pointer to the next. Please , tell me why it is an error and how to solve it

Comment: @JackAss `Node<T> temp = new Node<>(n);` is valid as of Java 7.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet My logic is that Node class should be ale to contain whatever type T the LinkedList class is created with. So Since I am creating LinkedList<String> the same should be conveyed to the Node class :)
And Yes , im using Java 7

Comment: Node<T> temp = new Node<>(n); // here in Left Hand Side(LHS) is the varialble name and Right Hand Side(RHS) is the object which it points. Now Node<T> temp , <T> can be any thing we know and the default is <Object> hence when you write new Node(n) actually implies new Node<Object>(n). if not you need to mention <T> . cant leave <> which compiler does not understand. Hence Compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Node` Constructor is not `public`, so it will not work if you call it from a class in another package.

Comment: The constructor will work as long as all the source files are in the same directory :)