# Why doesn't autoboxing work in this case with generics?

Tags: java, generics, object, integer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: Array of primitive data types does not autobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517751/java-array-of-primitive-data-types-does-not-autobox)

I've been doing some Java lately (mostly as a recap on what I did at university as my current job doesn't involve any Java at all) and one thing that never got introduced to us properly is Generics.

I've been doing the Generics tutorial on the Oracle Java website and I've been stumped by the following example that I modified a bit:

```
public static <Integer extends Comparable<Integer>> int countGreaterThan(Integer [] anArray, Integer elem) {
    int count = 0;
    for (Integer e : anArray)
        if (e.compareTo(elem) > 0)
            ++count;
        return count;
}
```

And I use this method to compare an Integer array with the following Integer:

```
Integer [] numarr = {1, 2, 3, 4 , 5};
Integer num = new Integer(5);

int count = Util.countGreaterThan(arrnum, num);
```

This seems to work fine, however if I pass a primitive array and a primitive int, it doesn't:

```
int [] arrnum = {1, 2, 3, 4 , 5};
int othernum = 3;

int count = Util.countGreaterThan(arrnum, othernum);
```

The compiler complains with:

```
method countGreaterThan in class Generics.Util 
cannot be applied to given types;
required: Integer[],Integer
found: int[],int
reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) 
Integer exist so that argument type int conforms to formal parameter type Integer
```

The tutorials seemed to be pretty adamant that Java will always autobox/unbox objects and primitives as necessary and yet it won't do it in this particular case, what am I missing?

Also what could be a good way to generalise this comparing method as much as possible? If I used T instead of Integer, then it would look for a T object, rather than whatever I pass to it.

I apologise if the post is confusing and if I seem pretty ignorant about the stuff I talk about above, it's just that I've been working primarily as a perl programmer (and not as particularly experienced one either) and generalising there seems as less of an issue (due to the lack of type enforcement).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: using `Integer` as a type variable is a really bad idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below seems to work as far as I can see:

```
public static <Integer extends Comparable<Integer>> int countGreaterThan(Integer [] anArray, Integer elem) {
    int count = 0;
    for (Integer e : anArray) {
        if (e.compareTo(elem) > 0)
            ++count;
        return count;
}
```

although I get a warning `"The type parameter Integer is hiding the type Integer"`. See `@ErichSchreiner`'s answer for an explanation of why auto-boxing won't work here.

A good generalisation of your method would be:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> int countGreaterThan(T[] anArray, T elem) {
    int count = 0;
    for (T e : anArray) {
        if (e.compareTo(elem) > 0) {
            ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

All you really care about is that `anArray` has the same type of elements as `elem` is, and that it is comparable to it's own type.

Comment: You did a better job of explaining the auto-boxing problem though, added a reference.

Comment: for best results, use `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`

Comment: @newacct: Good point, edited.

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration of `countGreaterThan()` hides the built-in type `Integer`. To clarify, consider the slightly modified version:

```
public static <I extends Comparable<I>> int countGreaterThan(I [] anArray, I elem) {
    int count = 0;
    for (I e : anArray)
        if (e.compareTo(elem) > 0)
            ++count;
        return count;
}
```

Now it should become apparent that your second attempt at calling can not work as there **can be no autoboxing done**. For generics to work, you need to supply objects, not primitives.

Comment: Aha, thanks for that! I assumed that since I could declare an ordinary method with an Integer return type and then pass a primitive to it without any problems, I could do the same with Generics.

I also tried passing a Generic class to the count method (something along the lines of `public class Box<T extends Integer>`) however that fails with:

` required: T[],T
  found: Generics.Box[],Generics.Box
  reason: inferred type does not conform to declared bound(s)
`

Is it safe to assume that I cannot pass generic classes to the countGreaterThan(with <T> as a signature) either?

Thanks!

@Keppil