# Insert int Array to ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Can I insert array to array and read it afterwards in Java? Something like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<>();
array.add([1,4,5]);
array.add([3,7,2]);
```

Array:

```
{ [1,4,5], [3,7,2] }
```

And read like:

```
print(array[0][1]); //prints 4
```

Thanks.

Comment: Not directly, but it wouldn't take much (IMO) to write the code for it

Comment: arraylist is a list, not array.  they are different thing. you may want to create a 2d array

Comment: I can't imagine any sensible Java code that would print 4 at [1][2] when arrays you have shown are added (even if you use some 2d array type like array of arrays)

Comment: Sorry for mistake, I'm human only...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could write `ArrayList<int[]>` and pass values like `.add(new int[]{...})`.

For example,

```
List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new int[]{1, 2, 3});
```

To print values out you should get an `int[]` array firstly by `get(int index)` and then get a value from this array by `[index]`:

```
System.out.print(list.get(0)[0]); // prints 1
```

---

About the mess in the comments.

1. **There are no raw types here.** I didn't write, for example, `List` or `List<Object>` anywhere.
2. `int[]` is an array, therefore it is a reference type and can be used as a generic parameter.
3. `int` is a primitive which doesn't work/use with generics. Consider its wrapper class - `Integer`.
4. I used the diamond `<>` above. Why? To prevent "boilerplate code".

> In Java SE 7 and later, you can replace the type arguments required to invoke the constructor of a generic class with an empty set of type arguments (`<>`) as long as the compiler can determine, or infer, the type arguments from the context. This pair of angle brackets, `<>`, is informally called the diamond.
>   `List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<>();`
>   `List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<int[]>();` is equivalent to the previous

Comment: @Berdesdan I think you're mixing up terms. `int` is a primitive type, not a raw type.

Comment: fixed your -1, i dont get this community sometimes. your answer is completely fine

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis spot on - "A raw type is the name of a generic class or interface without any type arguments"

Comment: talking about the primitive types and such, arrays are not primitives, even when they're arrays of primitives like we're looking at here. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517751/java-array-of-primitive-data-types-does-not-autobox

Comment: @AndrewTobilko sorry about the confusion, you are not wrong. I was confused about raw/primitive types. Jeutnarg's link cleared it up..

Comment: @Berdesdan And even that is incorrect. The diamond operator `<>` is ok here.

Answer (score 3):

to quickly fill an arrayList with fewest lines of code :

```
    Integer[] numArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 9, 8, 7, 6};
    List<Integer> numList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(numArray));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add integer arrays to an `arraylist`, but then the arraylist must be defined as:

```
List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<int[]>();
```

**In Fact a more generic version would be**:

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

The `array.add([1,4,5]);` is **implemented correctly** as

`list.add(new int[]{1,4,5});`

The `print(array[1][2]);` is **implemented correctly** as:

```
System.out.println(((int [])list.get(1))[2]);
```

Comment: Why would you use a more generic version when you know int[] is the type you want to use?

Comment: I never said that you must use it, I just wanted the OP to be aware of it.

Comment: But if anything, it's just going to confuse OP more. IMO it clutters up your answer, but it's not a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList is List type.

If you want to create 2d array (array inside array)

```
int[][] a = new int[][]{{1,4,5},{3,7,2}};
System.out.println(a[0][1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use ArrayList of ArrayLists

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> intArrays = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    //rows
    for(int i =0;i<4;i++)
    {

        intArrays.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
        //cols
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
            intArrays.get(i).add(j);
        }
    }
    //rows
    for(int i =0;i<4;i++)
    {

        //cols
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
            System.out.print(intArrays.get(i).get(j));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

This has been tested and is working.

```
    int[] ar = {10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20};

    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i:ar){
        list.add(new Integer(i));

    }
    System.out.println(list.toString());

    // prints : [10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20]
```