# Comparable Interface (Heap)

Tags: java, data-structures, heap

This is heapifying the array question and 
this is my constructor of the `heapcls` which extends to Comparable

```
heapcls(T[] arr,boolean flag){   

        this(flag);
        for (T item : arr) {
            this.data.add(item);
        }
        for(int i=this.data.size()-1;i>=0;i--){
            this.downheapify(i);
        }
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[]arr={7,8,9,5,11,3,10,1,6,2,4,12,0,-1,13};
        heapcls<Integer> client=`enter code here`new heapcls<>(arr,false);
}
```

> ```
>   this statement is giving ," Cannot infer type arguments error"
> ```
>
> how should I change my CompareTo(by default function) to rectify the error.
>   since i havent overridden the bydefault CompareTo function.pls guide me.

Comment: By the way, there's no need to call `downheapify` on every element of the array: just the first half. You can speed up your code by changing your `for` statement initialization to `this.data.size()/2`.

Answer (score 1):

The actual issue is that you're trying to pass an `int[]` to a constructor which has `T[]` as a parameter. Since the type on the left-hand side of the assignment is `heapcls<Integer>`, the constructor is supposed to have `Integer[]` passed to it as an argument.

[Type arguments to generic types can't be primitive types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721546/why-dont-java-generics-support-primitive-types) and [arrays of primitives aren't autoboxed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517751/java-array-of-primitive-data-types-does-not-autobox). (Autoboxing an array would require allocating an entire new array.)

It seems like you could fix this just by using `Integer[]` instead of `int[]`.

I'm not really sure why we get the "cannot infer type arguments" message in cases like this. I think it's a bug with the Java compiler when using the diamond type (i.e. `<>`) and the arguments to the constructor aren't applicable to any of the declared constructors. (Here's a much more minimal example showing the same issue with the error message: http://ideone.com/wJx16i.)

In any case, your code shouldn't compile, but because you're trying to pass an `int[]` as an argument to a constructor which effectively has `Integer[]` as a parameter, not really because the type arguments can't be inferred.

As a side note, class names in Java start with an upper-case character by convention, so your `heapcls` should be `HeapCls` (and probably just something like `Heap`).