# why I cannot pass double[] to Double[]

Tags: java

I have this snippet :

```
static class Foo {
    Double[] array;
    Double value;

    public Foo(Double[] array) {
        this.array = array;
    }

    Foo(double value){
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] array = new double[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    double value = 10;

    new Foo(value);   //this is normal
    new Foo(array);   //syntax error cannot resolve constructor Foo(double[])
}
```

I get syntax error

> cannot resolve constructor 'Foo(double[])'

**Why** I can pass variable of type `double` to method that receive `Double` , **but** I cannot pass an array of type `double[]` to method that receive `Double[]` as parameter

Comment: There is no autoboxing/unboxing for entire arrays.

Comment: As mentioned in above comment, there is no auto boxing for array. YOu can find the same discussion in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45918075/why-autoboxing-doesnt-work-in-arrays

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Answer (score 4):

Because `double` is primitive and `Double` is not. So when you assign a primitive vs Wrapper boxing/unboxing works. But there is no such mechanism for whole array.

And also `double[]` have no null's at all upon initialisation because they hold primitives where as `Double[]` can hold nulls and they can't be interchangeable and they are incompatible.

Answer (score 2):

In Java arrays are objects and created using `new` operator. Your method expects a `Double[]` type of object and you are passing `double[]` type of object.

You are expecting java should perform auto-boxing/unboxing, But that happen between primitive types and their wrapper classes not for array, as they are objects in themselves.

Reference: [JLS: Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html)

Answer (score 1):

Autoboxing only works for primitive types (`double` -> `Double`). `double[]` and `Double[]` are arrays, each with their different types, and Java will not box/unbox these automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, autoboxing doesn't work for arrays.

But in your example, you can initialize our double array this way.

```
Double[] array = new Double[]{1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0};
```