# Creating an Array object with generics

Tags: java, arrays, generics

So I'm trying to create a simple program that allows for me to put an array of Int, String, double.... to an object and the print it:

```
public class Array<E> {

    private E[] data;
    private int size;

    public Array(int size, E[] data)
    {
        this.size=size;
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++) this.data[i]=data[i];
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String s=new String();
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++) s+=data[i]+" ";
        return s;
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int A[]= {1, 3, 5, 7};
        Array<Integer> niza=new Array<Integer>(4, A);
        System.out.println(niza.toString());
    }

}
```

However it gives me this error whenever I try to create the object:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The constructor Array(int, int[]) is undefined

```
at test.Main.main(Main.java:8)
```

Any ideas of what's causing the problem and a possible solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Declare your array as this :``Integer A[]= {1, 3, 5, 7};``

Comment: Nope it's still not working.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko it is his own... but the current problem is explained in Jens answer, he now have  NPE due to `this.data` being null

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that

```
    int A[]= {1, 3, 5, 7};
    Array<Integer> niza=new Array<Integer>(4, A);
```

declares an array of `ints`, while the constructor expects `Integer[]`. `int` is a fundamental type, and is a different type than `Integer`. The compiler converts between `int` and `Integer` when possible and needed, [but this conversion is not defined for arrays.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517751/java-array-of-primitive-data-types-does-not-autobox)

If you declare your array as

```
    Integer A[]= {1, 3, 5, 7};
    Array<Integer> niza=new Array<Integer>(4, A);
```

[your code will compile, but fail with a `NullPointerException`](https://ideone.com/yekQ8a) because the member `data` is not initialized. [You can easily fix that with](https://ideone.com/yekQ8a)

```
private final E[] data;

public Array(int size, E[] data)
{
    this.size=size;
    this.data = Arrays.copyOf(data, size);
}
```

Although I would prefer to use `ArrayList` instead of arrays...

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I did and it failed with a NullPointerException. Why is it doing that?

Comment: your `data` field is not initialized.