# Generic methods java for Character and String

Tags: arrays, generics, methods

I'm looking for a quick solution about an issue in my following code. It is working but not how I wanted.

So,
**the idea is that I'm trying to pass an Character class array and convert it into ArrayList. Since I'm using generics, I specified:**

public  void fromArrayToCollection(**T[] a**,Collection e)

**and I guess this means I can pass what kind of arrays I want, such as Int array, char array,String array,double and so on**
But it won't let me pass an character array.
If I am passing a String array is it actually working
Why?
Thank you.

```
public class FuDaBi {
    static class StringToArray{
        public <T> void fromArrayToCollection(T[] a,Collection<T> e)
        {
            for(T x: a)
                e.add(x);
        }
        public <T> void fromStringToArray(T inputString, T[] array )
        {
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Character[] my_array = {'S','A','L','U','T'};
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

        String daniel[] = {"WV","Mercedes"};


        StringToArray myimp = new StringToArray();
        myimp.fromArrayToCollection(daniel,result);
        for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++)
        {
            System.out.println(result.get(i));
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: Array of primitive data types does not autobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517751/java-array-of-primitive-data-types-does-not-autobox)

Comment: char[] my_array = {'S','A','L','U','T'};  still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I made the ArrayList a String type instead of an Character.

ArrayList result = new ArrayList();